# Unable to connect to AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've created AWS RDS Postgres database and I tried to create a new database server to connect to AWS RDS database from PGadmin4 like so:

[image: Pgadmin4 creating new server connected to AWS RDS]

However, it throws an error message everytime im trying to create the new server:

[image: Error Message]

What I've done :

- Set public accessibility to yes
- Added inbound rules

  - Type : all traffic, source : anywhere,
  - Type : all traffic, source : my IP,

[image: Inbound rules]

One post that had similar issue to mine is [unable to connect to AWS RDS postgres instance from pgadmin4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60787480/unable-to-connect-to-aws-rds-postgres-instance-from-pgadmin4). The issue still persists despite having followed the suggested solutions.

Comment: The issue is only with PGadmin4? Can you connect to the db using cli, or from EC2 instance?

Comment: sorry, im quite new to this, how does one connect to db via cli?

Comment: for postgre there is [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html).

Comment: Also, did you place your rds into default VPC, or some custom one?

Comment: same error message connecting via cli. my vpc security group is set to default

Comment: You need to provide more details. Setup of your VPC? Which subnets did you use? Did you modify any network ACLs? What is custom source in your SG? What happenes when you try with `0.0.0.0/0`?

Comment: I used all the default settings that were given. I only changed my security group inbound rule. As for which subnets I'm using, I believe all of them are public subnets. im not rly sure if its safe to share your subnet here?

Comment: Try connecting from a different network (eg home vs office vs tethered via your phone). Sometimes corporate networks block certain types/ports of traffic. You'll need to update the Security Group to allow the different IP address for this testing.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, turns out my network is the issue. Its all working fine now thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to debug using the telnet command to know whether the issue is with your connection or with PGAdmin4.

```
telnet <endpoint> <port>
```

If the RDS instance is reachable via telnet then your connection is ok, else you need to allow the traffic.

Comment: Connecting To database-1.cqjtti***o5b.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5432: Connect failed. I can't connect via telnet. How can I allow the traffic?

Comment: Can you check the subnet in which you've launched the RDS instance if that is private or public? Also, check the security groups!

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of them are public subnets. I only have one security group and it is the default security group, which contains the inbound rules ive shown in the post.

Comment: Can you check the route tables of public subnets, if the Internet gateway (IGW) is attached or not?

Comment: yes all three of them are. all of them have destination as 0.0.0.0/0 and target of unique igw-xxxxx

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue beginers face. To resolve this issue folllow the below steps ( Make sure your RDS is publically Accisible)

1. Create a Two Route Table one for public access and one for Private access.
2. Create a Nat Gateway Using the Same VPC as used in the RDS instance.
3. Add the Nat Gateway to the PVT route table with 0.0.0.0/0 ip as showen in the below figure include the subnet in subnet association donot use the subnet of the availability zone of the RDS instance as that subnet will be used in PUBLIC ROUTE TABLE.. So Associate the other subnet to this ROute Table
   [image: Add the Nat Gateway to the PVT route table with 0.0.0.0/0 ip]
4. In the PUBLIC ROUTE TABLE add the following routes for 0.0.0.0/0 usin the internet gate way of your vpc. associate the subnet which belongs to RDS instances availability zone into this route table
   [image]

**Note:** Addition to this if you want to add a new Subnet to the RDS instance so that you can add a new subnet at the same availability zone of your RDS you can create a subnet in the same VPC aand add the subnet to (RDS Subnet Group)
[image]

To provide internet access to your aws lambda using the same RDS you can just attach the subnet used in private route table to your lambda function.